# Android, programmatically layout a button view?

Tags: android, layout, view

I am trying to programmatically define my program layout and add a button to it at a certain position. I am not using the layout xml as the content view.

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout;
    mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new
LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

I have then added a button that I want to apply the properties

```
layout align center
parent align left
height 60px
width 60px
```

here is the button so far

```
Button BtnNext = new Button(this);
    BtnNext.setWidth(60);
    BtnNext.setHeight(60);
    BtnNext.setFocusable(true);
    BtnNext.setId(idBtnNext);
    BtnNext.setText("Next");
    mainLayout.addView(BtnNext, 1);
```

Height and width DON'T work correctly.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it doesn't "work correctly?"  You might also want to consider use DIP instead of PX

Comment: Already answered below, it was a density problem. The reason I was confused is because layout editor sets it fine even when I type pixels, but I guess it does an automatic DPI detection and correction (or converts to dip as mentioned)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you can try by setting layout params

```
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  rel_btn.height = 60;
  rel_btn.width = 60;
  BtnNext.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);
```

You can also add rules and set margins for Button by setting relative layout params like

```
 rel_btn.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
 rel_btn.leftMargin = 220;
```

Answer (score 2):

Height and width will not be as u wished because your are not using Density-independent pixel (dip)
The value you set here is in pixel
You can convert the pixel into dip by
`final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        int dip = (int) (60 * scale + 0.5f);`
You will get more accurate result