# Center a WebView Programmatically

Tags: java, android, layout, webview

I am creating my controls programmatically, based on JSON received from a server. One of the controls I need to create is a `WebView` that is horizontally centred on the screen. This is simple in xml layouts as shown below using the layout_gravity option. But how do you do this in code, the `WebView` unlike `TextView` does not have a `setGravity(Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK)` method.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe LayoutParameter and rules will help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4048957/1063730

Comment: I'll have a look when I get home. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a RelativeLayout, then you can use LayoutParams when adding the view:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 1);
relativeLayout.addView(yourWebView, layoutParams);
```

Comment: Not had a chance to try this unlike my comment on the post below. But do you have to use center in parent and do you think this will work as the relative layout is added to the child of the main layout which is a linearlayput

Comment: If the RelativeLayout's width/height are set to fill_parent and the WebView is set to centerInParent inside the RelativeLayout, then the WebView will be centered in the RelativeLayout, and thus centered in the LinearLayout. Although, if all you have is a LinearLayout and a WebView, I would scrap the LinearLayout completely and just change it to a single RelativeLayout as having both would be unnecessary.

Comment: This didn't work either. The only way I got it to be centred was to specify the width/height in layourParams, but as I can't work out the width/height in advance, i've given up and set the width of the webview to be the same as the width of the screen.

Comment: If you want it to be the width of the screen you need to use fill_parent, editing the main post with the fill_parent part

Answer (score 0):

i use LinearLayout to show webview  and setGravity.

```
       LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    WebView view = new WebView(this);
    linearLayout.addView(view);
    setContentView(linearLayout);
```

it help you.

Comment: Thanks but i tried that already. The page I add the view to is a linear layout which fills the available space. So I wrapped the web view in a linear layout and set the gravity as you suggusted. Then added that linear layout to the main layout. It had no affect on the postioning of the webview .