# Positioning a WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a surface (which extends SurfaceView), an AdView and now I want to add a WebView, which I'm going to need to position dynamically.

For start, I'm trying to add my web view at the center and make its size the device's width and half its height. I'm with a 800X480 device and landscape mode, so for now I want to set its border at left=0, top=120, right=800, bottom=360, just for the sake of testing. Later on I'll want to be able to set it dynamically, but so far this doesn't even work:

```
private MySurface surface;
private AdView adView;
private WebView

.
.
.

// create the ad view
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, AD_MOB_ID);
adView.setAdListener(new MyAdListener());

// create the surface
surface = MySurface.getRef(this);

// set a listener for touch event
surface.setOnTouchListener(this);

// create the web view

webView = new WebView(this);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
LayoutParams webViewParams = new LayoutParams(800,240); // this works
webViewParams.setMargins(0, 120, 800, 360);             // this does nothing...

// create a relative layout
RelativeLayout l = new RelativeLayout(this);

// add the surface
l.addView(surface);

// add the ad view at the bottom
AdView.LayoutParams adViewParams = new AdView.LayoutParams(
AdView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
AdView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

adViewParams.addRule(AdView.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

l.addView(adView, adViewParams);

l.addView(webView, webViewParams);

setContentView(l);  

// load an ad
//loadAdMob();
```

when I later set the webview visibility to visible:

```
webView.loadUrl(url);
webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

It appears the right width and height but starts at the very top of the screen :(

Can anyone help ? Thanks.

Comment: This also did not have any effect: webViewParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it:

```
webView = new WebView(this);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams webViewParams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(800, 240);
webViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

RelativeLayout l = new RelativeLayout(this);
l.addView(surface);
l.addView(adView, adViewParams);
l.addView(webView, webViewParams);
setContentView(l);
```

credit goes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918226/center-a-webview-programmatically)